# What are the available transportation modes from Paris (Opera) to CDG?

Tags: airport-transfer, transportation, cdg

I have two heavy bags, so I am looking for good suggestions \ options to go  from the Hotel Westminster (perched between Opera \ Pyramides) to CDG for a 10AM Monday morning international flight.

Update: I should have noted there are two passengers. Tradeoffs to be considered include:

1. cost
2. speed
3. convenience (lines, pickup modality, etc)

Although I have seen at least 3 transportation options, I suspect there may be others and look forward to other good options.

Comment: Have you considered the [Roissybus](http://www.ratp.fr/en/ratp/r_61852/roissybus/): "Bus connecting Paris-Opéra with Charles de Gaulle airport?"

Comment: @ZachLipton: Thank you and yes: I have walked by the Roissybus station several times and visited their website.

Comment: Your "tradeoffs" are fairly straightforward.  Of course a taxi is most expensive, but it is wildly more convenient.  The hotelier will carry your bags, ***from next your bed*** and place them in the taxi.  You will step from the front desk in to the taxi.  Of course, taxi completely crushes the other options in terms of speed and convenience. The time it will take you to get to and wait for a bus you could be in the airport and checked-in. But, it's expensive.

Answer (score 2):

The Roissybus would be your best bet for a direct Connection (given your heavy bags). It runs from the Opera to the airport

Comment: how much is that bus, man?

Comment: @JoeBlow €8.50.